# Show test body, test steps for passing tests in Cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

When tests pass in Cypress it doesn't show the steps but if fails it shows all the steps and what step caused test to fail.

I want to see passing tests body/steps too.

Below image shows a passing test and a failing test. Failing test is much more informative. I want passing test to be like that too. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```js
 it('should select shipment method and type "test" into additional 
   notes', function () {
     cy.intercept('GET', 
  '**/GetDetailWithAvailableCampaign*').as('basketDetails')
  
  cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => { // If CheckoutJS throws an error, it will be caught here
    cy.get('[data-cy="information::forward"]').click()
    cy.url().should('include', '/basket/checkout/payment')
  
    cy.get('[data-cy="shipping::shipment_type"]').first().click()
    cy.get('[data-cy="shipping::shipment_type"]').should('be.checked')
  
    cy.get('[data-cy="misc::additional_message_checkbox"]').check({force: true}).should('be.checked')
    cy.get('[data-cy="misc::additional_message_textarea"]').should('be.visible').clear().type('Test')
  
    // there is no shipping::forward
    // cy.get('[data-cy="shipping::forward"]').click()
  
    cy.get('[data-cy="information::forward"]').click()
  })
})

it('should focus iframe and put a credit card', function () {
    cy.wait(4000)
    cy.url().should('include', '/basket/checkout/shipping')
    const iframeSelector = 'iframe[data-cy="payment::iframe"]'
    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('.btn-card-visa').click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('input#CardNumber').clear().type(Cypress.env('credit_card').number)
    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('input#Expiry').clear().type(Cypress.env('credit_card').expiry)
    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('input#HolderName').clear().type(Cypress.env('credit_card').holder_name)
    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('input#VerificationCode').clear().type(Cypress.env('credit_card').cvv)

    getIframeBody(iframeSelector).find('.btn-next').click()
}
```

Comment: please add the code you tried.

Comment: I don't think this issue is about the test codes but I added the tests. There should be some configuration for Cypress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, clicking on a test's name in the runner will expand and show all steps executed. In your case, *it is doing this*. But the issue you are running into is most likely that the `uncaught:exception` event you are waiting for in the first test is not occurring, and therefore no steps are executed. If you remove the `cy.on('uncaught:exception')`, you'll see the steps are executed.

Comment: i have comment , i have much each it ( test ) , sometimes its expand sometimes not expand . did u know why ?